# Regarding retractions of $X$ onto subspaces

Tags: general-topology, definition

Let $A \subset X$ be a subspace of $X$. Recall that a **retraction** of $X$ onto $A$ is a continuous map $r: X \to A$ such that $r(a) = a$ for every $a \in A$.

Let $X = \bf R$ endowed with the standard topology, and let $A$ be the closed interval $[0,1]$ endowed with the subspace topology. Clearly, $[0,1]$ is open in $A$, but not in $X$. Am I right to say that, in this case, there is no retraction from $\bf R$ onto $[0,1]$, since $r^{-1}([0,1])$ is closed, and therefore $r$ is discontinuous?

Comment: There is a retraction: Map each $x\le0$ to $0$, each $x$ in the interval to itself, and each $x\ge1$ to $1$.

Comment: I do not see how this changes the discontinuity of $r$; $r^{-1}([0,1]) = [0,1]$, which is closed in $\bf R$.

Comment: $r^{-1}(A)$ is actually the whole of $\mathbf{R}$! Why do you think it's just $[0,1]$?

Comment: Ah, of course, that's clever. I'm sorry. The main point is of course that $r(a) = a$ is only necessary for $a \in A$, which was the source of my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: It's okay, we all make mistakes like that sometimes. As long as you learned something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see in the answers and comments the existence of such a retraction.

I want to get to the point, which you have misunderstood:

Every topological space $Y$ is both, open and closed. And for EVERY function (in particular the continous ones) $f:X \to Y$, it holds that $f^{-1}$ is open and closed. This is because this preimage coincides with $X$. So in your example $r^{-1}([0,1]) = \mathbb R$, which is closed but also open, but not the same as $[0,1]$.

Hope it helps to clean up your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a retraction $r:\Bbb R→I$ where $I=[0,1]$
$$r(x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x\le0\\
x,&\text{if }0\le x\le1 \\
1,&\text{if }x\ge1
\end{cases}$$
We could also write $r=\min(1,\max(0,x))$.